# How to run a discord bot on a side thread

Tags: python, discord, aiohttp

So I have been needing to use a discord bot to notify me when I get a response using aiohttp in python, the problem is, aiohttp needs/is supposed to run on the main thread. I have been trying to find ways to run the discord bot on a side thread but havent found any. Any solutions?

Comment: Messages are delivered to a thread, not to a process.  You can't move the message loop.  Can't you spin your current app to a thread?  If not, I guess you'll have to run a second process.'

Comment: This question as written is very broad; can you share some code and a specific problem you're having? Otherwise the only way to answer the question is with rough speculation.